# "More particularly" vs "more specifically"

Tags: word-choice

Is "more particularly" synonymous with "more specifically?" Moreover, is it even a phrase? For instance:

> I went to Walmart yesterday to buy groceries. More particularly, I bought tomatoes and lettuce.

Answer (score 2):

'More particularly' is not an expression used in common English. I would call it ungrammatical. 'More specifically' is a grammatical phrase.

'Particularly' implies that you are being more specific than your previous statement so to say 'more particularly' sounds redundant.

As well, the way the word 'specific' is used is often to express different levels or extents of specificity. This isn't generally so for being particular.

With 'specific', it is common to indicate how specific you are being. For example, one can be 'very specific,' 'not specific enough,' or even 'too specific.' It is grammatical to ask 'Can you be a bit more specific?'

In summary, specificity can be used if you are already being specific, as long as you are as specific or more specific than before.

'Particular' implies that you were not already being specific and that you will be more specific now.

It is possible to become more specific in layers (I.e. Mammal, cat, ginger tabby).

Comment: I certainly grant that it is common" to indicate how specific you are being," but I don't understand how you can more specify something. So my view about "more specific" and "very unique" is that I avoid these phrases even though the rest of the world  holds that they are acceptable.